# LDAP is not delivering results

Tags: java, active-directory, network-programming, ldap

I currently face the problem that an LDAP-Query is passed to an LDAP-Server and the LDAP-Server does not deliver results.

The query: (&(objectCategory=user)(mail=tester@oop-expert.de))

The given E-Mail is meant to not be found. So an empty result is expected.

In most environment configurations this query will pass perfectly and the LDAP returns an empty result immediately.

I broke down the problem to something that may relate to the network or host from where the query is sent. So the query will be fine if sent from one host/network and from another host/network the LDAP-Server will "starve" my LDAP-Client so the LDAP-Client closes the connection for a client-side timeout.

On the other hand: searching for an email that exists will always lead to an immediate result. Doesn't matter from which host/network.

The LDAP-Server is an Active Directory. There a several domain controllers providing an LDAP-Service, configured "round robin". Access per ip or dns does not make any difference on this subject.

The communication is secured via ssl. (ldaps)

In all situations the connection was established. So authentication and passing the query to the LDAP went fine.

Authorization should not be an issue either. I used the same LDAP user for all situations.

The LDAP client is always a JAVA implementation using `InitialContext`.

```
private InitialDirContext createDirContext(String principal, String credentials) throws NamingException {

    if (credentials == null || credentials.isEmpty()) {
        throw new LDAPLoginException();
    }

    return new InitialDirContext(createEnvironment(principal, credentials));
}


private Hashtable<String, String> createEnvironment(String principal, String credentials) {

    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, this.ldapUrl);

    // To get rid of the PartialResultException when using Active Directory
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");

    // Needed for the Bind (User Authorized to Query the LDAP server)
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principal);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, credentials);

    return env;
}
```

The code that builds and executes the query:

```
private LDAPUser getLDAPUserInfoByUniqueField(String attr, String value) {
    DirContext serviceUserContext = null;
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;

    try {

        String searchString = "(&(objectCategory=user)(" + attr + "=" + value + "))";

        serviceUserContext = createDirContext(this.serviceUserPrincipal, serviceUserCredentials);
        results = serviceUserContext.search("", searchString, createSearchControls()); // blocking...

        return createLDAPUserInfo(results);

    } catch (LDAPLoginException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new LDAPFatalException(e);
    } finally {

        try {
            if (results != null)
                results.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
        }

        try {
            if (serviceUserContext != null)
                serviceUserContext.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Utility methods:

```
private LDAPUser createLDAPUserInfo(NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results) throws NamingException {
    LDAPUser ldapUserInfo = null;

    if (results.hasMore()) { // blocking here

        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();

        String sAMAccountName = extractsAMAccountName(result);
        String distinguishName = extractDistinguishName(result);
        String department = extractDepartment(result);
        String email = extractEmail(result);

        ldapUserInfo = new LDAPUser(sAMAccountName, distinguishName, department, email);

    }
    return ldapUserInfo;
}


private String extractsAMAccountName(SearchResult result) throws NamingException {
    Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
    Attribute attr = attrs.get("sAMAccountName");
    return (String) attr.get();
}
```

The exception:

```
de.oopexpert.business.ldap.LDAPFatalException: javax.naming.PartialResultException [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: oopexpert.de:636 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]]
at de.oopexpert.business.ldap.impl.LDAPImpl.getLDAPUserInfoByUniqueField(LDAPImpl.java:90)
at de.oopexpert.business.ldap.impl.LDAPImpl.getLDAPUserInfoByEmail(LDAPImpl.java:57)
Caused by: javax.naming.PartialResultException [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: oopexpert.de:636 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreImpl(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:242)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMore(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:189)
at de.oopexpert.business.ldap.impl.LDAPImpl.createLDAPUserInfo(LDAPImpl.java:139)
at de.oopexpert.business.ldap.impl.LDAPImpl.getLDAPUserInfoByUniqueField(LDAPImpl.java:84)
```

Any hints?

Comment: Your words are a little unclear. Are you saying that you NEVER get a result  back when the result set should be empty? If so, how do you know? Program hangs waiting for a response forever?

Comment: "Are you saying that you NEVER get a result back when the result set should be empty?" No. Only if I query the LDAP-Server from a special host with the special query that should return an empty result. "Program hangs waiting for a response forever?" Correct. But at some point the client of course stops the request due to a client-side timeout.

Comment: Whats special about this host?

Comment: The host is located in another network (TCP/IP). The host runs linux rather than windows (my machine). The web application is deployed to a tomcat on a docker container on the host. On my machine I only use tomcat without a docker environment. But If you ask, whats so special about the host that the LDAP-Server is not responding... thats exactly my problem :-).

Comment: You haven't shown how you programmed the query, or sent it, or what the results were, or the exception, or the timeout, ...

Comment: Thats a pretty complicated setup you have with many components that could be to blame. I would move the host into the same network as the ldap server or else set up an identical machine to test on to rule out routing/firewall issues first.

Comment: As I said: Queries, that are expected to return at least one result record will work (known email adress). I added the StackTrace and the invoking JAVA code.

Comment: You haven't shown `createLDAPUserInfo()`. We can't guess what your code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We struggled with four persons what is going on. We figured out, that it has something to do with "name resolution problems" on the server side when "following refferals". The customer specific environment configuration inherently prohibits us to prevent this behaviour. **So we came up with a workaround.**

As we are operating in an active directory domain we have global catalog servers. The important statement to this is from Microsoft "technet":

> The global catalog is a distributed data repository that contains a searchable, partial representation of every object in every domain in a multidomain Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) forest. The global catalog is stored on domain controllers that have been designated as global catalog servers and is distributed through multimaster replication. Searches that are directed to the global catalog are faster because they do not involve referrals to different domain controllers. 
>   (from [What Is the Global Catalog?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728188%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))

The phrase "do not involve refferals" leads us to my JNDI environment configuration where I set the following:

```
env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
```

So as I did that, the LDAP-Server will ask other LDAP-Servers if the result of a query *seems to be* incomplete. This was confirmed by our administrators when I started the query and they debugged it on TCP-Level.

Somehow, I maybe do not really represent it correctly, the name of the other LDAP-Server could not be resolved which leads the client to starvation as the first LDAP-Server waits for resolution.

We tried to omit the client parameter "Context.Refferals=follow". Here we get immediate response. But the response wasn't as expected:

```
javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name ''
```

This came up because the first LDAP-Server has the opinion to return incomplete data.

Our administrators say that this can never be the case, because "every domain controller" is a "Global Catalog Server".

**So my workaround is: I will deal with this exception and interprete it as "no result".**